# Disabling submit button until all fields have values

Tags: jquery

I want to disable my submit button until all the fields have values..
how can I do that?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#register').attr("disabled", true);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        Username<br />
        <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" /><br />
        Password<br />
        <input type="text" id="pass_input" name="password" /><br />
        Confirm Password<br />
        <input type="text" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" /><br />
        Email<br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />     
        <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" />
        </form>
        <div id="test">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about attacks? using enable and disable attributes are not secure....Just click f12 in your browser, find the submit button in the html, and then remove the disabled ! It will submit the form even if the inputs are empty.

Comment: @Elnaz Obviously, it is not useful as a security and any user-supplied data must be treated as a potential attack. But in many cases it is a good UX.

Comment: @Elnaz I would hope that you would perform input validation on the server side, so this isn't really an attack vector, just a means of preventing premature form submissions.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Check out this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/).

### HTML

```
// note the change... I set the disabled property right away
<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
```

### JavaScript

```
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        }
    });
})()
```

The nice thing about this is that it doesn't matter how many input fields you have in your form, it will always keep the button disabled if there is at least 1 that is empty. It also checks emptiness on the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) which I think makes it more convenient for usability.

Comment: so How Can I do it with radio buttons? I've a multiple choice form

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie it may be better to set the disabled attribute to 'disabled' and remove the disabled attribute using .removeAttr('disabled') instead of setting it to be false.

Comment: You might have a problem with above script untill you define empty variable before using it at the top of the script. so put this after (function() { ---> var empty;

Comment: HUGE HOLE HERE!!! If someone turns off the javascript, button is disabled. It should be set to disabled also via javascript at the beginning of the script execution.

Comment: The keyup event won't fire if form element is type number. Better use change event instead (or both).

Comment: Using `form input` instead of `form > input` also selects inputs inside child elements (e.g. `div`s).

Comment: @FernandoCorreia Your comment really helps!!! This piece of JS cannot select child elements inside divs inside the form!

Comment: @Hristo. Hi, I am Your code is very helpful for my project. but in my project i have select option and radio also there. can you help me

Comment: I would use `$('input[type="submit"]')` to target the submit button not the ID, future proofs it a tad.

Comment: Also use `$("form input").on("keyup change",function () { }` instead of just `keyup` as this will catch autocomplete values too...

Comment: What about radio or even checkboxes ? Does not work for them.

Comment: using `$("#formID > input")` not working for me. It works with: `$("#formID input")`

Comment: This isn't JS. Please provide a Vanila JS solution if possible also

Comment: @proofzy I discovered if I have a <p> tag between the submit button and the text field then it doesn't work unless I remove the '>' symbol like you suggest.  If I replace <p> with <br>&nbsp;<br> then it works with the '>'.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 26):

```
$('#user_input, #pass_input, #v_pass_input, #email').bind('keyup', function() {
    if(allFilled()) $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
});

function allFilled() {
    var filled = true;
    $('body input').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') filled = false;
    });
    return filled;
}
```

[JSFiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/tKQFN/), works :)

Comment: If you empty one input, the submit button keeps enabled. After the `if` statement I added `else{$('#register').prop("disabled", true);}` So now, if you empty one of the inputs, the register button is disabled again.

Answer (score 9):

For all solutions instead of ".keyup" ".change" should be used or else the submit button wont be disabled when someone just selects data stored in cookies for any of the text fields.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 8):

All variables are cached so the loop and keyup event doesn't have to create a jQuery object everytime it runs.

```
var $input = $('input:text'),
    $register = $('#register');    
$register.attr('disabled', true);

$input.keyup(function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });
    trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DKNhx/3/

Comment: Would this still work if the browser caches the values and prepopulates the fields?  Or would a keyup event be required?

Answer (score 5):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kF2uK/2/

```
function buttonState(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if($(this).val() == "" ) return false;
        $('#register').attr('disabled', '');
    })
}

$(function(){
    $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input').change(buttonState);
})
```

Comment: i think this is the cleanest

Answer (score 2):

I refactored the chosen answer here and improved on it. The chosen answer only works assuming you have one form per page. I solved this for multiple forms on same page (in my case I have 2 modals on same page) and my solution only checks for values on required fields. My solution gracefully degrades if JavaScript is disabled and includes a slick CSS button fade transition.

See working JS fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/bno08c44/4/

**JS**

```
$(function(){
 function submitState(el) {

    var $form = $(el),
        $requiredInputs = $form.find('input:required'),
        $submit = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');

    $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $requiredInputs.keyup(function () {

      $form.data('empty', 'false');

      $requiredInputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
          $form.data('empty', 'true');
        }
      });

      if ($form.data('empty') === 'true') {
        $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('title', 'fill in all required fields');
      } else {
        $submit.removeAttr('disabled').attr('title', 'click to submit');
      }
    });
  }

  // apply to each form element individually
  submitState('#sign_up_user');
  submitState('#login_user');
});
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="submit"] {
  background: #5cb85c;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background 600ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:disabled {
  background: #555;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>Sign Up</h4>
<form id="sign_up_user" data-empty="" action="#" method="post">
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
 <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Password Confirmation" required>
 <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="secret">
 <input type="submit" value="signup">
</form>

<h4>Login</h4>
<form id="login_user" data-empty="" action="#" method="post">
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
 <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> remember me
 <input type="submit" value="signup">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Built upon [rsplak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657496/rsplak)'s answer. It uses jQuery's newer [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the deprecated [.bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/). In addition to input, it will also work for select and other html elements. It will also disable the submit button if one of the fields becomes blank again.

```
var fields = "#user_input, #pass_input, #v_pass_input, #email";

$(fields).on('change', function() {
    if (allFilled()) {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

function allFilled() {
    var filled = true;
    $(fields).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            filled = false;
        }
    });
    return filled;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriscrowley/6fdxLkq0/)

Answer (score 1):

This works well since all the inputs have to meet the condition of not null.

```
$(function () {
    $('#submits').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#input_5').change(function () {
        if ($('#input_1').val() != '' && $('#input_2').val() != '' && $('#input_3').val() != '' && $('#input_4').val() != '' && $('#input_5').val() != '') {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: In my case it works ok after filling in all fields but when I empty one of the fields, the #submit remains `attr('disabled', false)`. I believe the correct behaviour would be to change to `attr('disabled', true)` status.

Answer (score 1):

## If you happen to be using vanilla JavaScript...

```js
let fields = document.querySelectorAll('form > input')
let submitButton = document.querySelector('form > button')

fields = Array.from(fields) // Turn fields into an Array to access the ".every" method.

fields.forEach(field => {
  field.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    submitButton.disabled = !fields.every(field => field.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grave digging... I like a different approach:

```
elem = $('form')
elem.on('keyup','input', checkStatus)
elem.on('change', 'select', checkStatus)

checkStatus = (e) =>
  elems = $('form').find('input:enabled').not('input[type=hidden]').map(-> $(this).val())
  filled = $.grep(elems, (n) -> n)
  bool = elems.size() != $(filled).size()
  $('input:submit').attr('disabled', bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all inputs that are not hidden and not directly under the form (inside child elements like divs)

```
    (function() {
    $('form :input:not(:hidden)').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form :input:not(:hidden)').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        }
    });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps to check the field time by time, whenever the input field become null it detect and disable the button again

```js
function validate() {
  var valid = true;
  valid = checkEmpty($("#user_input")) && checkEmpty($("#pass_input")) && checkEmpty($("#v_pass_input")) && checkEmpty($("#email"));

  $("#register").attr("disabled", true);
  if (valid) {
    $("#register").attr("disabled", false);
  }
}

function checkEmpty(obj) {
  var name = $(obj).attr("name");
  $("." + name + "-validation").html("");
  $(obj).css("border", "");
  if ($(obj).val() == "") {
    $(obj).css("border", "#FF0000 1px solid");
    $("." + name + "-validation").html("Required");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Username<br />
  <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" onkeyup="validate()" /><br />
  Password
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="pass_input" name="password" onkeyup="validate()" /><br />
  Confirm Password<br />
  <input type="text" id="v_pass_input" name="v_password" onkeyup="validate()" /><br />
  Email<br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" onkeyup="validate()" /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled/>
</form>
```