# enable or disable submit button on completion of form using jquery in asp page

Tags: jquery, css, asp-classic

enable  or disable submit button on completion of form using jquery in asp page.
i want tto enable the button and change the class of button on my asp page when user fill all the necessary field 
please help me i have found many code but not even one is of my work
please help me
i have tried ths

```
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        }
    });
})()
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted your code correctly? It does not start with $( and has a () at the end.

Comment: Does your submit button have attribute id="register"? Do you get any js errors in the browser?

Comment: yes,no any error occur ,i need to specify all the field individually

Answer (score 0):

try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/5QJvK/2/

```
$(function(){
   $('form > input.field').keyup(function() {
        var empty = false;
        $('form > input.field').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('form input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('form input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```