# javascript: prevent submit if all text fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqueryform

i am using this javascript to disable my form submit button until a user has typed in the textarea field. once the textarea is populated the submit button is no longer disabled.

however, whilst this is working for a single text area i now want to find a way to make this work so that if i had four text input fields then to keep the submit button disabled until all of them are NOT empty/populated with text.

heres what im using at the moment:

```
<form action=\"includes/welcomestats.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"form1\" onSubmit=\"if (this.display_name.value == '') {return false;}\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"display_name\" id=\"display_name\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Display Name\">
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"welcome-submit2\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Next ->\" id=\"submit\"/>
</form>

    <script>
    $(function(){

        $("#submit").submit(function(e){

          if($("#display_name").val()==""))
          {      
            e.preventDefault();
           }
        });        

    });
    </script>
```

but now i am adding more text input fields to my form, so i need the script to keep my submit button disabled until all the text fields are populated, can anyone help me please?

i want to add these text fields to my form:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"public_email\" id=\"public_email\" maxlength=\"50\" placeholder=\"Email Address\">

<input type=\"text\" name=\"phone\" id=\"phone\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Phone Number\">

<input type=\"text\" name=\"age\" id=\"age\" maxlength=\"2\" placeholder=\"Display Age\">
```

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery might be worth mentioning it and adding it to the tags as well. It given more visibility to the question under number of tags..

Comment: if you are dynamically load DOM then you need to use it as `$(document).on('submit','#submit',function(e){`

Comment: Sorry for the accidental retag

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.filter` method to get all the empty input element, then check the length.

```
if ($('#form1 input').filter(function(){return $(this).val().length == 0;}).length > 0) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me, do i keep this line in the <form tag onSubmit=\"if (this.input.value == '') {return false;}\" and do i put the text id as input?

Comment: @BearJohn Nope, you do not.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('form input').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':empty')){
           $('form #submit').preventDefault();
        }
    });    

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/

```
<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />

(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
    }
});
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the OR operator - `||`

So if `display_name` is empty OR `public_email` is empty etc...

```
$(function(){

    $("#submit").submit(function(e){

      if($("#display_name").val()=="" || $("#public_email").val()=="" || $("#phone").val()=="" || $("#age").val()=="")
      {      
        e.preventDefault();
       }
    });        

});
```

Comment: do i still have to include them all in the form tag like this: onSubmit=\"if (this.display_name.value == '') {return false;}\"> ?

Comment: @BearJohn Yes, if you're doing it inline with the `form` tag - But the jQuery should pick up the event without the need for the `onSubmit` event attribute in the `form` tag at all

Answer (score 0):

Give all of your text fields you want to include in this validation a class `class="required"` or something along those lines, then you can do this

```
var empty = $('.required').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() == "" }).length;
if(empty === 0){
   //Enable your submit button all text fields have a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function checkInputs(form) {
  var inputs, all, 
      status = true;

  if (form && form instanceof jQuery && form.length) {
    inputs = form.find("input[type=text]");

    all = inputs.length;

    while (all--) {
      if (!inputs[all].value) {
        status = false;        

        break;
      }
    }

    return status;
  }
}
```

And demo here: http://jsbin.com/afukir/1/edit

EDIT: I've added `instanceof` to make sure that this function will only proceed if the form is actually a jQuery object.