# How can validate params in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, ruby-on-rails-2

Here is the table:

```
|policies|
  |id| |name| |date|
    1    ABC   2013-01-01 
    2    DEF   2013-01-21
```

Here is the controller:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @policies = Policy.find(:all,:conditions=>['date BETWEEN ? AND ?',params[cam],params[:cam2] ])
   end
end
```

Here is the model:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<% CalendarDateSelect.format=(:hyphen_ampm )%>
<% calendar_date_select_style "silver" %>
<% translation_calendar %>

<% form_tag :controller=>"policy",:action=>"index" do %>
  From: <%= calendar_date_select_tag  "cam", params[:cam]  %>

  To:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag  "cam2",params[:cam2] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
<% end %>

<% @policies.each |p| do %>
  <%= p.date %>
<% end %>
```

How can block the SEARCH button until my 2 calendar text have values?

I tried this:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :cam
end
```

Please somebody can help me please or maybe a javascript?

I will appreciate all kind of help.

Here is what friends told me:

```
 named_scope :by_calendar_date,lambda { |cam1, cam2| }  {
    if cam1.nil? && cam2.nil?
       scoped
    elsif cam1.nil?
       where("date < ?",cam2)
    elsif cam2.nil?
       where("date > ?", cam1)
    else
       where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?",cam1,cam2)
    end
}
   #this would perform the same functionality so both are not needed but just for edification
def self.by_calendar_date(cam1,cam2)
    if cam1.nil? && cam2.nil?
       scoped
    elsif cam1.nil?
       where("date < ?",cam2)
    elsif cam2.nil?
       where("date > ?", cam1)
    else
       where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?",cam1,cam2)
    end
end
```

Comment: Validation shouldn't occur in a view, it should happen in a controller.

Comment: oh you are searching for a trick to validate your calendars, and if they don't have values the submit button won't work

Comment: Your lambda is incorrect it is a block so the execution should happen between the curly brackets and after the piped variables. I updated my answer so you can see. You don't need both methods pick the named_scope or the self.by_calendar_date method.

Comment: @engineersmnky I want my params to be really necessary before click on SEARCH

Comment: Okay in that case use a jQuery validation like the one listed below

Comment: I updated my methods to reflect Rails 2.3 style I have no way to test this since I do not run 2.3 but it should work based on the documentation. Obviously still does not have any affect on the validation prior to submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/

### HTML

```
// note the change... I set the disabled property right away
<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
```

### JavaScript

```
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
        }
    });
})()
```

The nice thing about this is that it doesn't matter how many input fields you have in your form, it will always keep the button disabled if there is at least 1 that is empty. It also checks emptiness on the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) which I think makes it more convenient for usability.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You need to translate this jQuery code into Prototype code

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a search feature you do not need to validate in my opinion you could just do this

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
    named_scope :by_calendar_date,lambda{|cam1,cam2|
        if cam1.nil? && cam2.nil?
           {:conditions => {}}
        elsif cam1.nil?
           {:conditions => ["date < ?",cam2]}
        elsif cam2.nil?
           {:conditions => ["date > ?", cam1]}
        else
           {:conditions => ["date >= ? AND date <= ?",cam1,cam2]}
        end
   }     
end
```

call with

```
def index
  @policies = Policy.by_calendar_date(params[:cam1],params[:cam2])
end
```

This way the user can set either param individually or none at all

Comment: just replace `scope` with `named_scope` and `->` with a `lambda { |cam1, cam2| }` block to make it compatible ....

Comment: @MrYoshiji's answer will also work using `named_scope` and a `lambda` which rails 3 shorthanded to `->(...)`

Comment: I edited the post and wrote that MrYoshiji wrote but still not working

Comment: I got undefined method `by_calendar_date' for #<Class:0x7f32999b29b8>