# onkeyup not working when text box is empty

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I have a text box and a submit button beside it. The button is in disabled state. Once the user type something in the text box, it should be enabled. That is working fine. But once the user starts typing, it gets enabled. And if backspace is used to make the field empty, the button still remains in enabled state.

```
<html>
<body> 
  <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()"> 
  <input type="button" id="a" disabled = "true" value ="click me"> 
  <script> 
    function myFunction() 
    { 
      var x = document.getElementById("fname"); 
      x.value = x.value.toUpperCase(); 
      if(x.value != " ") 
      { 
        document.getElementById('a').disabled=false; 
      } 
    } 
  </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put else statement on your condition that makes the button disabled if textbox is empty. try the code below.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="button" id="a" disabled = "true" value ="click me">

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    if(x.value != "")
{
   document.getElementById('a').disabled=false;
}else {
document.getElementById('a').disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. All you have to do is, check for length property and add an else statement to disable the button when there is no value in the textbox.

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type="button" id="a" disabled = "true" value ="click me">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
if(x.value.length > 0)
{
   document.getElementById('a').disabled=false;
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('a').disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this code in HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
```

and make below changes in javascript

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
    }
});
```

I think it really work well.Hope you get your desired operation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the if else condition to work respectively, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/Lz0ma0zf/), And try to avoid adding event listeners directly to the markup:)

```
$('#fname').keyup(function() {
  //console.log('wor');  
    if(!$(this).val() == '') {
        $('#a').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else{
        $('#a').prop("disabled", true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your Script as shown below**

```
   function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("fname");
        x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
        if (x.value.length != 0) {--here is the change
            document.getElementById('a').disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            alert('Empty');
            document.getElementById('a').disabled = true;
        }
    }
```