# jquery each function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Im check through a form to see if the inputs have been filled out. I Keep the submit button disabled until the required fields are filled out. However if I type in the textarea which is required the button is enabled even if the previous required fields are not filled out.

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/v2to0fcw/1/

here is the markup

```
<form action="/contact" method="post">
    <div class="form-row firstName">
        <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid first name.</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row lastName">
        <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid last name. Example: Smith</p>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row phone">
        <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid phone number. Example: 555 555 5555</p>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row email ">
        <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid email. Example: person@email.com</p>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message*" required class="form-control required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
</form>
```

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    (function() 
    {
        $('.required').on('keyup change', function() 
        {
            $('.required').each(function() 
            {
                if (this.value == '') 
                {
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
                }
            });

        });
    })()
```

The button will not enable unless you fill out all required fields but if I skip the first three and type in the message the button is enabled. Whats going wrong?

Comment: If the final `<input>` is not an empty string then the button's `disabled` attribute is removed; which is exactly what your code is written to do.

Comment: by final input you mean textarea? So if (this.value == '') is only targeting final input? I also tried if ('.required' == '')

Comment: The problem is that you're adding and removing the attribute each time through the loop. So at the end, it contains the setting from the last iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/efbonrnr/1/

```
    $('.required').on('keyup change', function() 
    {
            var requiredFieldsCompleted = true;
        $('.required').each(function() 
        {
            if (this.value == '')
            {
                requiredFieldsCompleted = false;
            }
        });

        if (requiredFieldsCompleted)
        {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');

        }
        else
        {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

    });
```

The issue was you were disabling / enabling the field after each check, without taking into the previous items. As such, only the last required field would affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we need to maintain a flag instead of adding and removing `disabled` attribute again and again, that is causing this issue see my comment with variable `var flag;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {
    $('.required').on('keyup change', function() {
      var flag = false; // we need to check if any of the field is empty then set it to true, we will decide the send button to be enabled or disabled after that
      $('.required').each(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
          flag = true;
        }
      });
      if (flag) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  })()

  $('#firstName').on('change', function() {
    var firstName = this.value;
    if (/^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/.test(firstName) == false) {
      $("#firstName").css('border', '1px solid #d22020').val('');
      $('.firstName .form-alert').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $("#firstName").css('border', 'none');
      $('.firstName .form-alert').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

  $('#lastName').on('change', function() {
    var lastName = this.value;
    if (/^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/.test(lastName) == false) {
      $("#lastName").css('border', '1px solid #d22020').val('');
      $('.lastName .form-alert').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $("#lastName").css('border', 'none');
      $('.lastName .form-alert').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

  $('#phone').on('change', function() {
    var phone = this.value;
    if (this.value !== '') {
      if (!$.isNumeric(phone)) {
        $("#phone").css('border', '1px solid #d22020').val('');
        $('.phone .form-alert').css('display', 'block');
      } else {
        $("#phone").css('border', 'none');
        $('.phone .form-alert').css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  })

  $('#email').on('change', function() {
    var email = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (!email.test(this.value)) {
      $("#email").attr('placeholder', 'johnsmith@email.com').css('border', '1px solid #d22020').val('');
      $('.email .form-alert').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      $("#email").css('border', 'none').attr('placeholder', 'Email *');;
      $('.email .form-alert').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
.form-row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.label-control {
  float: left;
}
.required-label:after {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
  content: '\f069';
  color: rgba(245, 0, 0, 1);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 8px;
}
.form-control {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 9px 9px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 1);
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.form-control:hover,
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
textarea {
  min-height: 175px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
input[type=submit]:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.form-alert {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(210, 32, 32, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/contact" method="post" class="form">
  <div class="col-dual">
    <div class="form-row firstName">
      <label for="firstName" class="label-control required-label">First Name:</label>
      <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid first name.</p>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row lastName">
      <label for="lastName" class="label-control">Last Name:</label>
      <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid last name. Example: Smith</p>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row phone">
      <label for="phone" class="label-control">Phone:</label>
      <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid phone number. Example: 555 555 5555</p>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row email ">
      <label for="email" class="label-control required-label">Email:</label>
      <p class="form-alert">Enter a valid email. Example: person@email.com</p>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-dual">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="subject" class="label-control required-label">Subject:</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject*" required class="form-control required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="message" class="label-control required-label">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message*" required class="form-control required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/v2to0fcw/5/

Snippet:

```
 if (this.value == '') {
   $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   return false;
 }
```

You are using validation(enable/disable submit button) over "required" class, which is used on multiple input elements. When you edit the last textbox, the validation runs over all input elements(which has required class) & the result of final element(which is text area in your case) alone is taken into account, which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/efbonrnr/9/

No need to run the whole loop when first empty field is found.

```
if (this.value == '') {

      requiredFieldsCompleted = false;          
      return false;
}
```