# enable form submit button when password requirements are verified

Tags: javascript, button, passwords

I have made a form to change the password for a user. When the syntax requirements are meet and the confirm password field is the same I want to enable the submit button.

Here is my code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="submit.disabled = true;">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="password" id="pass1" name="new_password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="checkPasswords();" required="" style="border-radius: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: #b2b2b2;" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="pass2" name="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeyup="checkPasswords();" required="" style="border-radius: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: #b2b2b2;" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button id="random" type="button" value="Generate Random Password" name="random" onclick="generate_password()" >Generate Random Password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <button id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset Form" name="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Set Password" disabled="disabled" name="submit">Set Password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    (function() {
        $('form > button').keyup(function() {

            var empty = false;
            $('form > input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
            } else {
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled'); // updated according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637790/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-with-jquery-ie
            }
        });
    })()
</script>
```

I have removed the syntax checking for the sake of clarity.

The Set Password button does to activate when both fields are filled out. Can anyone shed light on where I have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have `onkeyup="checkPasswords();"` in your input fields - you didn't define that function anywhere.
Second - in your code you trying to handle keyup event on 'form > button', instead of input.