# jQuery function does not work for all fields of the same class

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jQuery code to disable a submit button in a form when the values are empty. the code works fine for all entries except for `.action_manager` (which is a `textarea` generated dynamically in a table)in which by filling only the first row, the button is enabled. I want all the fields to be filled before the `submitbutton`is reactivated. **Only one** instance of `action_manager` is enough to get the button enabled ( which is **not** what I want)

```
 $('document').ready(function(){

        var submitButton = $('input[name="store_values"]');
        checkValues();

        $('select.actuallevel').on('change',function(){
            checkValues();
        });
        $('select.targetlevel').on('change',function(){
                checkValues();
            });
        $('select.quarter_manager').on('change',function(){
            checkValues();
        });
        $('select.year_manager').on('change',function(){
            checkValues();
        });

        $(".action_manager").each(function()
        {
           $(this).on('change',function(){
                checkValues();
          });
        });


        function checkValues(){
            submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".actuallevel > option:selected[value=''],.actuallevel:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".targetlevel > option:selected[value=''],.targetlevel:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".quarter_manager > option:selected[value=''],.quarter_manager:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".year_manager > option:selected[value=''],.year_manager:empty").length > 0 ||
                !$.trim($(".action_manager").val())


            );
            //submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".targetlevel > option:selected[value=''],.targetlevel:empty").length > 0);
        }
    });
```

The textarea field is the following:

```
echo "<td><textarea class='action_manager' id='action-".$inf['Competence_ID']."' name='acto-".$inf['Competence_ID']."'>";if (isset($inf['actiontext'])){echo $inf['actiontext'];}echo "</textarea></td>";
    echo"<td>";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values

Comment: Use `$(document)` instead of `$('document')`

Comment: @tbraun89, I do not want to change the whole code for a small bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have inserted the .action_manager textareas dynamically, they were not present when your document has been loaded. Therefore, your attached events to .action_manager textareas will not be active for new textareas.

Here's the proper way to attach the events to the new and old .action_manager textareas:

```
   $(document).on('change','.action_manager',function(){
        checkValues();
  });
```

EDITED ANSWER:

Use the following function instead

```
        function checkValues(){
            var action_managerfilled = true;
            $(".action_manager").each(function(){
               if (!$.trim($(this).val())){
                    action_managerfilled = false;
                    return false;
               } 
            });
            submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".actuallevel > option:selected[value=''],.actuallevel:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".targetlevel > option:selected[value=''],.targetlevel:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".quarter_manager > option:selected[value=''],.quarter_manager:empty").length > 0 ||
                $(".year_manager > option:selected[value=''],.year_manager:empty").length > 0 ||
                !action_managerfilled
            );
            //submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".targetlevel > option:selected[value=''],.targetlevel:empty").length > 0);
        }
```

It seems that $('.action_manager').val() returns the value of the first textarea only, on all cases instead of checking the values of each textarea of the class '.action_manager'; hence the .each() function above to fix the issue.

Comment: This did not help. All the other fields are also generated dynamically, and still it works for them. They are all `select`fields. The only difference is that this one is a `textarea`

Comment: by dynamically, i meant they are added on load based on values from the DB

Comment: Please post a snippet of your html code; Might help us zero-down on your real problem.

Comment: https://www.friendpaste.com/6nxj1LsHGGt8NLD0yOwzBu
I dont know how easy it could be for you to detect things..

Comment: Your checkValues() function returns true even if i remove the .action_manager condition from the function. Therefore the problem doesn't lie there. Still testing it out..

Comment: Answer modified. Tested and working :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `on` delegated event **for dynamically generated elements**..and **you don't need to use `$.each` loop here , the selector selects all the element starting with that class**...

```
$(document).on('change','.action_manager',function(){
     checkValues();
});
```

however, it is recommneded to use the closest static parent that is present in the document than the `document` itself

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this did not solve the problem. I think I might have some problem in the function itself?