# Do not search if the search field is empty (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this basic Wordpress search form, I don't want users to be able to search if they leave the search field blank, preferably with javascript, how is this done?

Comment: add a javascript test: if $("#the-search-field").val() == '') do nothing;

Answer (score 2):

*Many ways lead to Rome...* But here is one solution.

So, say your search form input field has and `id` called `query` and you want to disable the `submit` button until the user has entered at least 1 character.

```
$('#query').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}).keyup();
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fxqsc86s/

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#search').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})();
```

and remember to disable the button by default:

```
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer taken from previous stack overflow question: [Disabling submit button until all fields have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this. 
It will check either your TextBox is empty

```
if ($('#TextBoxId').val() === '') {
// Your coding will go here.
}
```