# Show button when specific inputs are valid

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML form with multiple inputs. Some have the class `required`.

I want to show the "submit" button once *all* of these fields have a value.

I tried using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").hide();

    $('.required').on('keyup', function () {
        if($(this).val() !== "") {
            $("#submit_button").show();
        } else {
            $("#submit_button").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

but this shows the button if just one input is not blank.

Is it possible to do this for multiple inputs, once all the inputs with the `required` class are not blank?

**CheckRequired** function

```
function CheckRequired(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    var emptyElements = $form.find('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value === ''
    });

    if(emptyElements.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();

        emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect").attr('title', 'This field is required');

        //alert(emptyElements.attr("id"));
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");

        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values

Answer (score 6):

You have to check all required input on `keyup` with a loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").hide();

    $('.required').on('keyup', function () {
        var showBtn = true;
        // Check all inputs
        $('.required').each(function () {
            showBtn = showBtn && ($(this).val() !== "");
        }); //Edited
        // Hide or show the button according to the boolean value
        $("#submit_button").toggle(showBtn);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i am trying to use this however its telling me `showBtn` is false using `alert(showBtn);` . I have one text input with a class of required and when i type in the input, it alerts saying `false`

Comment: Hi @charlie, can you post a JsFiddle with your code and the `alert` line? It will be easier to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Adding jquery in your JsFiddle make it works correctly : https://jsfiddle.net/jxozk956/1/

Comment: i see the fiddle is working, but in my code it doesn't seem to be. still showing false

Comment: If you have the same code, it may be something else in your application that make this script not working. I can't help you without more information, please edit you question to add more snippets (or ask another question).

Answer (score 5):

The logic is straightforward:

1. Assume we'll show the button.
2. Look at each required input.
3. If any of those is empty, we need to hide the button, and don't need to check any more inputs.

And don't just watch `keyup`. That won't catch data pasted in via mouse/etc.  I'd also watch `change` and `blur`, to be safe.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show submit button *only* when all
  // .required fields have a value
  //
  var checkRequired = function() {
    var allValid = true;   // assume we're ready

    $('.required').each(
      function() {
        if (this.value.trim() === "") {
          // fail as soon as we hit an empty field
          allValid = false;
          return false;    // this ends the each() loop
        }
      }
    );

    $('#submit_button').toggle(allValid);
  }

  $('.required').bind('keyup change blur', checkRequired);
  
  checkRequired();  // start off in a correct state
});
```

```css
.required {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="required" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" class="required" />
  <input type=submit id=submit_button value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note that we call `checkRequired()` at startup, so that if the fields already have values, we'll show the button appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").hide();

  $('.required').each('keyup', function () {
    if($(this).val() !== "") {
        $("#submit_button").show();
    } else {
        $("#submit_button").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.each('keyup', ...` is not a valid use of `.each()`: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var flag = true;
            $('.required').keyup(function () {
                $('.required').each(function (index, responce) {
                    if ($(this).val() == "") {
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                });
                if (flag == true) {
                    $('#submit').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#submit').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" style="display:none;" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Users generally don't access multiple controls at a time. More importantly, events are processed one at a time. So you can just use a counter to check whether all required fields have been filled out, without needing to check all fields on every `keyup` event. You just need to keep track of whether a field was valid before, in order to not mess up the counter. Here is an efficient and effective solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#submit_button');
    var required = $('.required');
    var counter = 0;
    var trigger = required.length;
    button.hide();

    required.on('keyup', function () {
        var self = $(this);
        if(self.val() !== '') {
            if (!self.data('valid') && ++counter === trigger) button.show();
            self.data('valid', true);
        } else {
            if (self.data('valid')) --counter;
            button.hide();
            self.data('valid', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fa1LsLfh/1

Comment: Okay, i have tested and got it working changed my `required` class to something else. i think the issue is to do with another function as when i remove this, its starts to work fine. see the function called `CheckRequired` in my question

Comment: What starts to work fine when you remove what? What is your question? I am glad to help but please be more specific.

Comment: I have a function called `CheckRequired` which i have put into my original question. when i remove this function, your code starts to work fine.

Comment: Just from the code posted here, I see no reason why these functions should interact. Could you show the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code. It will work for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").hide();

    $('.required').on('keyup', function () {                    
           ToggleSubmitButton();
    }); 
});

function ToggleSubmitButton()
{
    $("#submit_button").hide();
    var getRequiredLength = $('.required').length;
    var nonempty = $('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value != ''
    }).length;

    if(getRequiredLength ==  nonempty){
        $("#submit_button").show();
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are truly `required` you can use the :invalid pseudo-class to fetch all required fields that are empty, if that collection's length is <1 you know all required fields have been filled.
If they only got the class required you could use JS to set the property too.
This also works for all other validated fields like email fields or stuff, so I would prefer this method.
Here is an example of how it works:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#testform input').on('keyup', function() {
    if(jQuery('#testform input:invalid').length < 1)
      {
        jQuery('#testform .dependend_submit').show();
       }
    else
      {
        jQuery('#testform .dependend_submit').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.dependend_submit {display: none;}
input {display: block;}
input:required {border-left: 1px solid red;}
input:not(:required) {border-left: 1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testform">
  <input type="text" name="text1" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="text2" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="text3" />
  <input type="text" name="text4" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="text5" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="dependend_submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question. Let me add another approach to handle this.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="a" value="" required>
  <input type="text" name="b" value="" required>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_button" disabled>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#submit_button {
  display: none;
}

#submit_button.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var submit = $('#submit_button'),
    required = $('input[required]');

required.on('keyup', function() {
    if (0 == required.filter(function() { return '' == this.value; }).length) {
        submit.addClass('active').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

**How it works**

- The submit button is hidden by default using CSS. This avoids that it might flash shortly, when the page is loaded. It is also `disabled`.
- The required input fields have the attribute `required`, which might also show a browser validation info, if the input is empty. This is an alternative to using the class `.required`. You can still alter the selector from `input[required]` to `.required` of course.
- The submit button as well as all required fields are stored in variables (`submit` and `required`). This is to avoid *a lot* of re-querying on each `keyup` event handler.
- Finally on each `keyup` the previously selected inputs are filtered for empty `value`s. If the result is empty (`0 == list.length`), the button is shown by adding a CSS class `active` (could be named `enabled` or similar as well of course). This has the advantage that you could add things like a transition etc. easily. It also enhances decoupling of your CSS and JavaScript.

**Final thoughts**

Using `keyup` might work on simply text inputs. If you have other inputs you want to track, like checkboxes, select dropdown etc., you might consider using 
`.on('input change')` on the `form` itself instead.

You could also disable and hide the button as well, if a field becomes empty again, like:

```
if (0 == required.filter(function() { return '' == this.value; }).length) {
  submit.addClass('active').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
  submit.removeClass('active').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/1r7aq4ay/1/)