# Call if statement every time an input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make it so that in my form the user cannot click the submit button until every field has an option selected. I originally tried this with a while loop and it created an infinite loop. I converted it to an if statement and added code to call the if statement every time something on the form is changed, but still the submit button never becomes clickable.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dtyekbho/)

```
if(($('input[type=text]').val() === '') || (!($('input[name=class]').is(':checked'))) || (!($('input[name=race]').is(':checked')))) {
    $(' input[type=submit]').css('pointer-events', 'none');
}
else{
    $(' input[type=submit]').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
}

$('input[name=user]', 'input[name=race]', 'input[name=class]').change(function(){
    if(($('input[type=text]').val() === '') || (!($('input[name=class]').is(':checked'))) || (!($('input[name=race]').is(':checked')))) {
        $(' input[type=submit]').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    }
    else{
        $(' input[type=submit]').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no else condition in your code..

Comment: @Rayon edited question with else condition, still does not work

Comment: check at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values) here you will find solution.

Comment: [shorter way](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/det87606/1/)

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla All good answers. Kartik you should submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it, but I am wondering what the .length in your example is used for?

Comment: `.length` in my fiddle will give you checked checkboxes count.if count is `0` then `!0` will give `true`...@Shniper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and shorter way to accomplish your task.

```
$('form#newPlayer').submit(function(){ // bind form submit event
   if($('input:text').val() == "" || !$('input[name="class"]:checked').length || !$('input[name="race"]:checked').length)
   {
     alert("all fields required");
     return false; // prevent form submission.
   }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/det87606/1/)

Answer (score 1):

why not use required attribute ? Here is a link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

If you want more sophisticated validation, take a look at this 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: these sites cannot be reached.

Comment: is there a way like this to require a selection for radio inputs?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field

Comment: u should use the built-in support, unless you have complicated validation rules, then try use javascript or js plugin

Answer (score 1):

Multiple selectors should we wrapped in a quote and separated by comma(`,`)

> `jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )`

**Note:** Also wrap `value` of the `attribute` in quotes(`"`)

> `jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )`

```js
if (($('input[type="text"]').val() === '') || (!($('input[name="class"]').is(':checked'))) || (!($('input[name="race"]').is(':checked')))) {
  $(' input[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', 'none');
} else {
  $(' input[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', '');
}
$('input[name="user"],input[name="race"],input[name="class"]').change(function() {
  if (($('input[type="text"]').val() === '') || (!($('input[name="class"]').is(':checked'))) || (!($('input[name="race"]').is(':checked')))) {
    $(' input[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  } else {
    $(' input[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', '');
  }
});
```

```css
#newPlayer {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  color: #8b0909;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 275px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
#newPlayer h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#newPlayer p {
  max-width: 275px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #c10606;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#newPlayer input[type=submit] {
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="newPlayer">
  <h3>Username:</h3>
  <input type="text" name="user" />
  <br>
  <h3>Please Choose a Class:</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="class" value="archer" />Archer
  <input type="radio" name="class" value="mage" />Mage
  <input type="radio" name="class" value="warrior" />Warrior
  <br>
  <h3>Please Choose a Race:</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="race" value="Orc" />Orc
  <input type="radio" name="race" value="Elf" />Elf
  <input type="radio" name="race" value="Human" />Human
  <input type="radio" name="race" value="Worg" />Worg
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <p id="descript"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write validate function which return true if all conditions are met or false if not. Then on click run the function and if it returns true then do form.submit()

```js
function validateData() {
  
  var result = true;
  
  if(!$('.yourinput1').val()) {
    result = false;
  }
    
   if(!$('.yourinput2').val()) {
    result = false;
  }
     
  
  return result;
  
  }



$('#yourbutton').click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault();

  if(validateData()) {
    
    $('#yourForm').submit();
  
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

From problem statement , it seems you are looking to `disable` the `submit` during **initial page load** and also if **all fields are not selected** & enable it only if **all fields are selected**.

So if it the case you need to initially **disable** submit button.

For that you can use `disabled` attribute.

Here is the change I did

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="true" class = "disableSubmit"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.disableSubmit{
  cursor:no-drop; // this will let user know button cannot be selected
}
```

**JS**

```
// function which will validate every field
function _validateFields(){
  var _textField = $('input[type=text]').val();
  var _secondField = $('input[name=class]').is(":checked");
  var _thirdField = $('input[name=race]').is(":checked");
  if((_textField === undefined || _textField ==="") || _secondField == false || _thirdField == false){
    return false;
   } 
  else{
    return true;
  }
}


$('input[name="user"],input[name="race"],input[name="class"]').on('change keyup',function() {
  if(_validateFields()){
    $(' input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled",false).removeClass('disableSubmit');
  }
  else{
   $('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled",true).addClass('disableSubmit');
  }
})
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nHbYCjVu1GhQal91WH44?p=preview) for demo