# Enable button if the mentioned input boxed are filled using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<input type="text" id="message1"/>
<input type="button" class="sendButton" value="submit"/>
```

This code displays two input boxes and one submit button.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);

    $("#message,#message1").bind(" change",function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    });
});
```

This is my jQuery to enable and disable buttons. But it enables the button, if one of the field is filled.I want to enable it only when both the input fields are filled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling submit button until all fields have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#message'&&'#message1').keyup(function(){
$('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false)
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message"/>
<input type="text" id="message1"/>
<input type="button" class="sendButton" value="submit" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 2):

So add checking for both elements and just check the `val()`. You don't need to access the `length`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);

   const message = $('#message');
   const message1 = $('#message1');

   $("#message, #message1").on("change",function() {

      if(message.val() && message1.val()){
        $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
      }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple small solution. Instead of checking for hardcode IDs and `change` event, you can actually use `input` with `input` event. This means, even if your input elements increase, this snippet would work:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(".sendButton").prop('disabled', true);
  if (checkIfEmpty()) {
    $(".sendButton").prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

function checkIfEmpty() {
  var flag = true;
  $('input').each(function() {
    var enteredValue = $(this).val();

    if ($.trim(enteredValue).length == 0)
      flag = false;
  });
  return flag;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="text" id="message1" />
<input type="button" class="sendButton" value="submit" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value of each `textbox` separately like following. And the you can use `prop` method like following.

```js
$("#message, #message1").keyup(function() {
  var msg = !$("#message").val(),
      msg1 = !$("#message1").val();
  
    $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', (msg || msg1));
}).keyup(); //to call on page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="text" id="message1" />
<input type="button" class="sendButton" value="submit" />
```