# Disable button in jQuery until all required fields have values (specifically with select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

At the moment I have the following form:

```
<table>
                        <tr><td class="labelTD"><label for="manifestNumber">Manifest No.:</label></td><td class="detailsTD"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Manifest Number" name="manifestNumber" id="manifestNumber" required></td><td><span class="requiredInput">*</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="labelTD"><label for="claimOrigin">Carrier Origin:</label></td><td class="detailsTD"><select id="claimOrigin" class="form-control" required name="claimOrigin">
                            <option></option>
                            @foreach($origins as $origin)
                             <option value="{{ $origin->id }}">{{ $origin->customer_name }}</option>
                             @endforeach
                            </select></td><td><span class="requiredInput">*</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="labelTD"><label for="originTerminal">Origin Terminal:</label></td><td class="detailsTD"><select class="form-control" required><option selected value="">Please Select</option><option value="CINC-Cincinatti">CINC-Cincinatti</option></select></td><td><span class="requiredInput">*</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="labelTD"><label for="date">Date Unloaded:</label></td><td class="detailsTD"><input type="date" name="claimDate" id="claimDate" class="form-control" required></td><td><span class="requiredInput">*</span></td></tr>
                    </table>
```

With this button at the end:

```
<button id="createManifestButton" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Manifest</button>
```

Now I've been trying to use others' examples but the script is refusing to work for me, namely the select option.

At the moment, I'm using this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/3370/ which is based on the answers from this question: [Disabling submit button until all fields have values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)

Unfortunately, in the comments, no one ever responded to the questions about other uses (like radio buttons, checkboxes), but the select issue was never responded to. So is there anything I can do? I want to disable the button specifically because it runs an AJAX script and for the sake of the average user, I just want to disable the button until all fields, including the select are filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the previous jsfiddle you linked, I forked and altered to code to work with your form. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/xrc35p7b/6/

```
(function() {
  $('.form-required').change(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.form-required').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('#createManifestButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#createManifestButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
})()
```

All form fields (of any type) with the class "form-required" will need to have a non-blank value in order to enable the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function() {    
    $('.manifestSubmit').change(function(){
      $('.manifestSubmit').each(function(idx, elm){ 

        if (elm.value == 'Please Choose' || elm.value.length == 0) {
          $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          return false;      
        }

        if ((idx+1) == $('.manifestSubmit').length)
          $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
      });
    });
})()
```

You can do what says "Rasmus Stougaard" with the option tag and avoid the condition (elm.value == 'Please Choose' || )

Answer (score 1):

In your example the select "blank" option should have the value "" like this:

```
<option value="">Please Choose</option>
```

Check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/3380/